# What does "consequence-free chance" mean?

Tags: meaning, attributive-nouns, compound-adjectives

I read this sentence on [TIME](http://time.com/4977185/bob-corker-donald-trump-feud-reality-show/) (Oct.23 2017),

> Having announced that he will retire at the end of 2018, Corker, once a key Trump ally, could emerge as a leading check on some of the President’s worst impulses. As enduring as Trump’s support is among his shrinking base, the war of words was a reminder that rest of the GOP would turn on Trump in a minute if given **a consequence-free chance**.

I don't understand the meaning of the "consequence-free chance", will somebody please be kind enough to explain it?

Comment: Meaning that Trump tends to be retaliatory against those of either party who publicly criticize him.

Comment: @MarkHubbard you should write an answer, your comment provides explanation of context which is very important to understanding expressions, combined with the explanation of what "consequence-free" means.

Comment: Thank you. I would, but Clare and Jeff Morrow have already provided very useful answers.

Comment: By the way, you should have said "read it *in* Time". I know that in Italian you read things "on" a book or newspaper, and I suppose your native language has the same rule. Never take English prepositions for granted! :)

Answer (score 14):

"Chance" here is used in its sense of "opportunity."

"Consequence-free" is a compound adjective meaning "without any harmful result."

Thus, a "consequence-free chance" means an "opportunity [to act] without any result that may harm [the actor]."

Comment: i get it now, i thought "free changce" was phrase.

Answer (score 13):

It's not *free chance* you want to look at, but *consequence-free* as a modifier of *chance*. This means a chance that is *free of consequence*.

Let's look at other uses of *-free*, including a couple of curious ones, for a broader understanding...

The *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED)   defines

**-free** as meaning

> Clear of something which is regarded as objectionable or problematic.

Yes, sometimes a consequence can be 'problematic'.

Other examples from the OED include

trouble-free
sugar-free
lead-free

There are also

pain-free
smoke-free
tax-free
guilt-free
worry-free
care-free
nicotine-free

This is similar to one definition of *free*

> Released from ties, obligations, or constraints upon one's action. (OED)

The definition continues

> Often used with reference to love and marriage; sometimes also (chiefly Sc.) with the sense ‘unmarried, single’.

The OED offers

**fancy-free**, which it defines as

> free from the power of love

and gives uses from 1600 (Shakespeare) and 1800 (Thackeray)

The Oxford Dictionary online defines it as

> Not emotionally involved with or committed to anyone.

Another OED definition of *free* is

> Released or exempt from, not liable to (a rule, penalty, or payment)

and offers

toll-free
"Free from toll; exempt from payment of toll. "

**scot-free**
Which does mean 'free from scots'  but not  'free from the Scots'. A *scot* was a *A tax or tribute paid by a feudal tenant to his or her lord or ruler in proportion to ability to pay; a similar tax paid to a sheriff or bailiff* (OED). So *scot-free* is not only the literal 'free from this tax' but also

> Without being punished; without suffering injury or harm.

So, *consequence-free* goes along with all these other examples of *free from ties, obligations, or constraints upon one's action.*

Comment: it's a vey detailed answer you posted ,thanks a million times.  i get it now.

Answer (score 2):

'**Consequence-free'** is a very interesting choice of words.

It is actually far stronger than the *usual expression* '**risk-free**'.

The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=risk+free&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crisk%20free%3B%2Cc0) of 'risk-free' shows how popular this expression has become, rising exponentially since the 1960s.

> Risk-free :used to describe something that does not involve any risk . . . [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/risk-free)

---

But the writer of the article did not say 'risk-free'.

The writer, above, sees this situation as *worse than a risk* (at present) and sees it as a 'consequence' that something unpleasant *will happen*. It is not a risk, is what is being stated, it is a **downright certainty.**

Therefore, says the writer, certain people wait, until the situation is free of *consequence*, before they act, safely.

> Consequence : a **result** of a particular action or situation, often one that is **bad** or not convenient . . . . [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consequence)

Comment: I’m guessing that the huge increase in the use of “risk-free” is because of its heavy use in modern economic theory and finance.  Especially in the context of “risk-free” rate, an interest rate on a bank deposit, for example.